# query multiple rows to summary result

Tags: sql

I try to get query of pass of fail result for each `ID`, The table is as following in attachment, each part has 0 to 3 channel and has result.I need check for each ID if all channel pass for that ID, the result is passed, otherwise, it is failed

```
ID   result     Channel
ID1  FAIL        2
ID1  PASS        1
ID1  FAIL        0
ID2  PASS        1
ID2  PASS        3
ID2  PASS        2
ID2  PASS        0
ID3  FAIL        0
ID3  PASS        1
ID3  PASS        2
ID3  FAIL        3
ID4  FAIL        1
ID4  PASS        0
ID4  PASS        3
ID4  FAIL        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID, result, count(Channel)
from t
group by ID, result
having result = 'PASS' and count(Channel) = 3
union all
select ID, result, count(Channel) 
from t
group by ID, result
having result = 'FAIL';
```

If not every ID has 3 channels then

```
select ID, result, count(Channel)
from t t1 where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t2.result = 'FAIL')
group by ID, result
union all
select ID, result, count(Channel) 
from t
group by ID, result
having result = 'FAIL';
```

For the perfomance competition (if 'FAIL' < 'PASS' in your DB, if it's not true use **max**):

```
select ID, min(result) n
from t
group by ID;
```

Comment: I may be wrong here (and interested to know if I am!) but would my solution have an efficiency gain by not using `union`?

Comment: very nice solution, simple and straight by using this: select ID, min(result) n
from t
group by ID;

Answer (score 0):

Since 'FAIL' is lower then 'PASS'

```
SELECT ID,MIN(result) AS result from yourtable group by id
```

If not every ID has 3 channels then

```
SELECT ID,case when count(id)=4 then MIN(result) else 'FAIL' end AS result  from yourtable group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it and, thanks to [common table expressions](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/11/18/best-postgres-feature-youre-not-using/), it's pretty readable too:

```
WITH bar AS (
    SELECT
        ID
        , channel
        , COUNT(result) AS result_count
        , SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pass_count
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY ID, channel
)

SELECT
    ID
    , channel
    , CASE WHEN result_count = pass_count THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS overall_result
FROM bar;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/328b6/12)